# How to change a vue data variable using this and (multiple) dynamic bracket notations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. I start of with a p element that contains the data variable "reportText.Scope_1_T_1", this variable contains the string: "Text to change";
2. On creation of this component, created() gets called and it fires off a call to the method createObject. The method createObject requires multiple arguments, but the only relevant argument is the second one, which includes the location of the data variable I want to change (in this case: "reportText.Scope_1_T_1");
3. The method createObject splits this argument/location based on the dots and returns an array. So the string "reportText.Scope_1_T_1" returns the array ["reportText", "Scope_1_T_1"];
4. Following that this array gets looped through and combined with the context (=this). First loop results in context = this["reportText"], second loop returns in context = this["reportText"]["Scope_1_T_1"].
5. After this I assign a new String to context (context = reply.fields)

My expectation was that this code would result in a change of the data variable this.reportText.Scope_1_T_1, but unfortunately nothing happens to this variable.

I have tried playing around with dot notation and bracket notation, but nothing really worked. For example if I try to change the code in my createObject method to this:

- this.reportText.Scope_1_T_1 = "New String"; or
- this["reportText"]["Scope_1_T_1"] = "New String";

It suddenly does work? I don't understand why. I even tried to see if I somehow make a copy of 'this' so it doesn't reference the same object, but as far as I see it doesn't make a copy. It does seems to be a reference problem, because it somehow points to a different location when I use my dynamic brackets.

Here is my relevant code(if you need more, please let me know):

```
<template>
  <p>{{ reportText.Scope_1_T_1 }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      reportText: {
        Scope_1_T_1: 'Text to change'
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.getters.getAppPromise.then(app => {
      this.createObject(app, 'reportText.Scope_1_T_1', 'String', '=irrelevantExpression');
    })
  },
  methods: {
    createObject(app, location, type, expression) {
      if (type === 'String') {
        app.createGenericOjbect(
          {
            fields: {
              qStringExpression: expression
            }
          },
          reply => {
            let context = this;
            location = location.split('.');

            location.forEach(item => {
              context = context[item];
            });

            context = reply.fields;
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out what the difference is between using my dynamically created context and a static context (like this: this["reportText"]["Scope_1_T_1"]). I think that's the key in solving this problem.

My code is based on this stackoverflow question:
[Javascript Square Bracket Notation Multiple Dynamic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146899/javascript-square-bracket-notation-multiple-dynamic-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the final step that won't work. Assigning a new value to `context` at the end will just update that local variable, not the property of the object.

Instead what you need to do is grab a reference to the relevant object and then update the property. To grab the object you need to drop the final section from the `location` path. That final section is then the property name that needs to be updated:

```js
let context = this;
const path = location.split('.');
const property = path.pop()

path.forEach(item => {
  context = context[item];
});

context[property] = reply.fields;
```

The syntax used for property access hides some asymmetry in how the parts of the path are interpreted.

Consider this example:

```js
const a = b.c.d.e
```

What happens is:

1. Start with `b`.
2. Grab the value in property `c`.
3. Grab the value in property `d`.
4. Grab the value in property `e`.
5. Assign that value to `a`.

All nice and symmetric, `c`, `d` and `e` all seems to work the same way.

Now consider flipping that example:

```js
b.c.d.e = a
```

This is very different.

1. Start with `b`.
2. Grab the value in property `c`.
3. Grab the value in property `d`.
4. Assign `a` to the property `e`.

In this scenario the `c` and `d` properties are still just read operations but the `e` is handled totally differently. That final part is a write operation instead.

The key thing to appreciate here is that the final part of a 'path' like this is special when you want to set the value. Normally this hides behind the syntax but when you want to break it down like in your example you need to be conscious of what is actually going on.

Whether you use `.` or `[]` notation makes no difference to this behaviour, though to access properties dynamically you have to use `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and bonus edit). Do you perhaps know what this behaviour is called? Because I would like to learn more about it, but I don't know what to search for. For example "referencing objects JavaScript" doesn't really help since it's way too broad.